# Which button called the function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two buttons which call the same function.  That functions signature is
`- (IBAction)eraseTextField {...}`
I would like to figure out what button called the function.  So I would like for the functions signature to be something like

`- (IBAction)eraseTextField: (id)sender {...}`.
Is there a way for the system to know to send the id of the calling object to a function that it calls?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `- (IBAction)eraseTextField: (id)sender` it will work with interface builder the way you think and sender will be the id of the object that sent the method in IB.

You can choose to write your methods with either `- (IBAction)eraseTextField and - (IBAction)eraseTextField:(id)sender` both work fine and the sender will be the id of the sender object.

Comment: Err, `sender` won't be the 'id' of the object, it will be the object itself.

Comment: Well the object itself is an ID

Comment: Ok, Justin. Thanks.  I am getting a "SIGABRT" and the function is never actually getting called - my breakpoint on the first line is never reached.  So I must have another problem.  Still it is very helpful to know that this actually is how the system is designed to work.

Comment: FYI, it was some system glitch.  I unhooked it and hooked up again and it worked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the tag attribute 
e.g. 
//using code

```
myButton1.tag = 1;
myButton1.tag = 2;
```

//using builder, go to the attributes inspector and set the tag field

then in
(IBAction)eraseTextField:(id)sender

you can see which tag it is, e.g.

```
switch(sender.tag) {
  case 1: //button 1 clicked
  break;
  case 2: //button 2 clicked
  break;
  default:
  break;
}
```

It's not a very good approach but it works.  For readability, you can assign the integer to a constant.  This approach maybe used if the button is not linked in the File Owner.  If it's linked, then you can compare the two directly. 
e.g.

```
if (myButton1 == sender) {
  //button 1 clicked
}
```

Comment: Thnaks, Manny.  This is exactly what I am trying to do.  Why is this not a very good approach?

Comment: use of tag is not a good approach because it will be hard to maintain / extend the logic later on.  Tags are just numeric values which do not mean anything to us and its value can easily change.  I advise to use it sparingly.